# Java function/method memory management

Tags: java, jvm

I have some questions about `Jvm` memory management:

> 1) if two methods or functions are running in background continuously, is it possible to find out that which one is taking more memory?
>
> 2) if this is possible then can we do this using Java Reflection ?

Comment: before/after execution your function put a debug log and in that print the difference of jvm heap memory

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487802/check-available-heapsize-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by *"taking more memory"*, but it is definitely possible to find which one *allocates* more memory. This can be done both from inside the application and from outside.

#### Inside the application

```
private static final com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean threadMXBean =
        (com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean) ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();

public void myAllocatingMethod() {
    long before = threadMXBean.getThreadAllocatedBytes(Thread.currentThread().getId());

    // ... some business logic that allocates memory ...
    byte[] array = new byte[500000];

    long after = threadMXBean.getThreadAllocatedBytes(Thread.currentThread().getId());
    System.out.println("Method allocated " + (after - before) + " bytes");
}
```

Note: this counts memory allocated in the context of current thread. If a method spawns new threads or executes some code in a thread pool, it's not obvious how to account the allocated memory to a particular method.

#### Outside the application

Use allocation profilers like [Java Mission Control](http://hirt.se/blog/?p=381).

**P.S.** Java Reflection has nothing to do with memory measurements.