# Besides ClassLoader and String.intern, what functions uses memory from the PermGen instead of the heap?

Tags: java, memory

Hi all I was wondering besides

1. the functions provided by [java.lang.ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) to load classes, and
2. [java.lang.String.intern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29).. ([Reference](http://eyalsch.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/oome/))

What other functions/classes uses memory from the PermGen space instead of the heap space?

Comment: do you mean only PermGen or all non-heap spaces? (If the latter please edit your post to reflect this.)

Comment: I don't believe String.intern() uses the perm gen. And CLassLoader doesn't use the perm gen directly, only indirectly. The Thread Stacks and NIO library use native memory which is neither.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I had that info from this article: http://eyalsch.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/oome/

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer From what I undestand, it's either the stack, the heap, the PermGen, or the *native* memory. If we share the same definitions, then yes I do only mean the PermGen space

Comment: @Pacerier If you have that info, perhaps you can change your question to make it clearer?

Comment: @Pacerier as I understand it its Heap, Non-Heap {containing PermGen and CodeCache} and JVM internals. The Stack is in Heap (afaik, but I'm unsure). Maybe this helps us both: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262328/how-is-the-java-memory-pool-divided

Comment: Did you have a particular implementation in mind? JRockit doesn't have a PermGen at all, and it is going away on HotSpot.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ok, have added that info in.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Hmm, I don't actually have a particular implementation in mind, basically any information regarding functions that do use the PermGen space would be desired.