# How do static methods run?

Tags: java

How do static methods actually run in Java? We usually invoke them using the class name, and do not create any object for them, but these are **objects** which actually can "run", not methods!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of `static method` Java loads the method when the class is loaded and shares the method with all the objects also and that's why an object is not necessary.
It's not always necessary to have an object in order to run a method.

**And** no, it's not the `object` that runs. It's the `method` that does the operation and objects or classes hold them as a property.

Comment: Note : Even *non-static* methdos are *loaded* when the class is loaded and there will only be *one instance* of non-static methods as well.

Comment: @TheLostMind thanks for your information, I really didn't know about that. Can you please provide me some link regarding this i mean loading of non static method. Thanks again

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821974/jvm-hotspot-where-do-all-the-methods-go-method-area-native-method-stack) might help. You might also want to go through JVM spec :)

Answer (score 4):

For static methods, a special keyword is *available* and added as part of the *byte-code*. It is called `invokestatic`.

From [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokestatic) :

***invokestatic***

> **Operation**
>
> *Invoke a class (static) method*
>
> **Description :**
>
> The unsigned indexbyte1 and indexbyte2 are used to construct an index
>   into the run-time constant pool of the current class (§2.6), where the
>   value of the index is (indexbyte1 << 8) | indexbyte2. The run-time
>   constant pool item at that index must be a symbolic reference to a
>   method (§5.1), which gives the name and descriptor (§4.3.3) of the
>   method as well as a symbolic reference to the class in which the
>   method is to be found. The named method is resolved (§5.4.3.3). The
>   resolved method must not be an instance initialization method (§2.9)
>   or the class or interface initialization method (§2.9). It must be
>   static, and therefore cannot be abstract.
>
> On successful resolution of the method, the class that declared the
>   resolved method is initialized (§5.5) if that class has not already
>   been initialized.
>
> The operand stack must contain nargs argument values, where the
>   number, type, and order of the values must be consistent with the
>   descriptor of the resolved method.

***Sample code :***

```
public class Example {

static void myStaticMethod() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    myStaticMethod();
}
```

}

***Byte code :***

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
   descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
   flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
   Code:
     stack=0, locals=1, args_size=1
        0: invokestatic  #31                 // Method myStaticMethod:()V
        3: return
     LineNumberTable:
       line 8: 0
       line 9: 3
     LocalVariableTable:
       Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
           0       4     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
```

***Runtime constant pool of class :***

```
...
 #31 = Methodref          #1.#32         // Example.myStaticMethod:()V
 ...
```