# tomcat 6 tenured memory issue

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

our application is deployed in tomcat 6 , while monitoring the tomcat performance we came to know that tenured memory is keep on increasing it's about to almost reaching committed memory.
I am worried after that it would stop working .

here are stats for tenured memory:
Used: 
   296,436 kbytes
Committed: 
   349,568 kbytes
Max: 
 1,398,144 kbytes
GC time: 
15.116 seconds on Copy (348 collections)

1.754 seconds on MarkSweepCompact (5 collections)

Please guide.
Thanks,
Aru

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by a memory leak in your application.

You can read get a bit of information about the different memory space: [How is the java memory pool divided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262328/how-is-the-java-memory-pool-divided)

I suggest you run a profiler (ex: [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html)) on your application, you will be able to detect objects that stay in memory (objects that do not get GC'ed).

Comment: The jvisualvm (included with recent versions of Java) and the Eclipse Memory Analyzer tools are useful also in investigating memory usage of an application and have the advantage of being free.

Comment: Is there any way we can install jprofiler or any other tool on our windows server and can monitor the remote application on linux server.

Comment: JProfiler can be installed on a server and be monitored from a distant PC. You need to configure the agentpath VM argument on your tomcat. You can find more information here: http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/indexRedirect.html?http&&&resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/helptopics/profiling/remote.html