# GetReserved code cache size

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I'm searching for an easy way to determine the current Reserved-CodeCache-Size from a Java application. 
Can anyone please give me a hint?

Comment: Do you mean of an application currently running in a jvm?

Comment: Yes, I do. I was just wondering if I could determine this parameter via console.

Comment: Jconsole is probably the answer then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1262474/1003855