# Why is the actual memory footprint of the JVM so much bigger than my Xmx?

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, heap-memory

My computer has 64GB of memory, and in Eclipse I set the default VM arguments like so:

```
-Xms512m -Xmx9g
```

I thought the 9GB is the biggest size my Java application could make use of. However, after I start my application for a while, I can see from the System Monitor that my Java application process is using nearly 16GB memory. How can it be larger than the VM argument I set as 9GB?

Comment: @Ravi it does not look like a duplicate, since the question is not what Xmx is but rather why it does not work as expected.

Comment: @user697911 which system monitor are you referring too and which number do you look at exactly?

Comment: As you are asking info about `Xmx` . So, it is well explained there. You need to share your task manager screen. To show us, as it is taking more memory

Answer (score 3):

`-Xmx` sets the maximum size of JVM 'heap' memory which is used for Java objects (organized into several 'generations': Eden, Survivor, Tenured/Old). *Outside* the heap JVM also allocates:

- loaded classes, and JITted code (as needed)
- thread stacks
- NIO 'direct' buffers
- native code: the JVM itself (including system libraries it uses), and code loaded/accessed by JNI or JNA
- data managed by native code

The first group are in CodeCache and PermGen through java 7 and Metaspace in java 8; although not in the heap these are reported through `MemoryPoolMXBean` like the heap spaces, and can be adjusted by *different* options like `-XX:MaxPermSize -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize`. The remaining groups cannot AFAIK be reported from Java. Stack size can be set with `-Xss` (but globally for all threads).

See also [What is the difference between Java Non Heap Memory and Stack Memory? Are they Same if not what is the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867989/what-is-the-difference-between-java-non-heap-memory-and-stack-memory-are-they-s) and [Java: non-heap-memory analyzes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329455/java-non-heap-memory-analyzes)