# Where are references of instance variables stored?

Tags: java

I know that the primitives and object references(for objects used inside a method) are stored on the stack frame and the actual objects are stored on heap. But I am not very clear on where the references to instance variables(which are reference type) are stored.

Can someone please explain where are those references(for instance variables) stored and if a methods wants to use any of the instance variables, then how exactly it works?

Comment: They're technically pointers and not references

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is the java memory pool divided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262328/how-is-the-java-memory-pool-divided)

Comment: @Progman, my question is not answered in that link. I am clearly asking about the references and not the actual objects.

Comment: What do you mean by "reference to instance variable"  - do you mean instance variables that are reference types, as opposed to instance variables of primitive types?

Comment: yeah exactly @Joni, that's what I am asking about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All instance variables are stored **within the object**, on the heap. There is no distinction between reference and primitive type variables in this. The *value* of the variable is a "reference" or "pointer" that is either the special `null` value, or it points to an object, through an implementation-specific mechanism (OpenJDK HotSpot JVM calls it "[oop](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/HotSpotGlossary.html)" - supposedly from "ordinary object pointer").

You can read more about the memory layout of objects in

- https://www.baeldung.com/java-memory-layout
- http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.com/2013/05/know-thy-java-object-memory-layout.html

Another matter is *how* instance variables are stored within the object: in what order do the go, or if they are stored packed. Instance variables are most likely not stored in source code order, but the details of this vary a lot between JVM implementations and versions.

OpenJDK now includes a tool you can use to inspect the object layout: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
public class Example {
    static String staticField = "staticField";
    String instanceField = "instanceField";

    public void foo() {
        String local = "local";
    }
}
```

### staticField

The string itself is on the heap, like all strings are. The static field named `staticField` is a reference that points at this. There's only one such reference (there is one place in memory of (usually*) 4 to 8 bytes pointing at it. This 'place in memory' is a bit tricky as to where it lives; generally on the heap, same place class files live.

### instanceField

This is much simpler to answer. There **is no such field**, at all, until someone makes a new object. And objects are.. on the heap. Imagine some entirely different code:

```
public void foo() {
    Example e = new Example();
}
```

This makes a new Example object and in so doing, we now have one instance of `instanceField`. The Example object is created on the heap, it occupies some memory. Part of that memory involves that 4 to 8 byte long reference (pointer) to the `"instanceField"` string, which also lives on the heap, probably in an entirely different spot. Then, the local field `e`, which lives on stack, will reference (point at) that.

So, we have `e` (living on stack), containing a memory address in the heap where an instance of `Example` lives, and within the memory used by that, there is a memory address that points at a different place on the heap where the string `"instanceField"` is located.

## local

Finally, there's `local`, which is 4 to 8 bytes on the stack, pointing at a string living on the heap.

*) Any JVM is free to implement this however they want.