# Java process snmp monitoring reports max values for Eden and Survivor Space are zero

Tags: java, snmp, wildfly-10

I'm monitoring a WildFly 10.1.0.Final Java process via SNMP port (configuring the `com.sun.management.snmp` properties) in a Linux box.

The problem is the reported **max** values for **Eden** and **Survivor** Spaces are zero.

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.110.1.11.4 = Counter64: 775946240
.1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.110.1.10.4 = Counter64: 3946840064
.1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.110.1.12.4 = Counter64: 3774873600
.1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.110.1.13.4 = Counter64: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.110.1.11.5 = Counter64: 4194304
.1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.110.1.10.5 = Counter64: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.110.1.12.5 = Counter64: 4194304
.1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.110.1.13.5 = Counter64: 0
```

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.110.1.2.2 = STRING: "Metaspace"
.1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.110.1.2.3 = STRING: "Compressed Class Space"
.1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.110.1.2.4 = STRING: "G1 Eden Space"
.1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.110.1.2.5 = STRING: "G1 Survivor Space"
.1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.110.1.2.6 = STRING: "G1 Old Gen"
```

The same monitoring script is used in a lot of other Java processes, which do not report this issue.

What can cause that?
Cann these values be zero?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `jvmMemPoolMaxSize` (OID `.1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.110.1.13`) is defined in [JVM-MANAGEMENT-MIB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/JVM-MANAGEMENT-MIB.mib) as type `JvmUnsigned64TC`, which seems kind of strange because Java specifically forbids the use of unsigned integer types.

The description for `jvmMemPoolMaxSize` implies that it's meant to represent the value returned by `java.lang.management.MemoryPoolMXBean.getUsage().getMax()`. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryUsage.html#getMax()) for that method says "This method returns -1 if the maximum memory size is undefined."

The description of `jvmMgmMIB` addresses the issue with this explanation:

> Where the Java programming language API uses long, or int,
> the MIB often uses the corresponding unsigned quantity -
> which is closer to the object semantics.
>
> In those cases, it often happens that the -1 value that might
> be used by the API to indicate an unknown/unimplemented
> value cannot be used. Instead the MIB uses the value 0, which
> stricly speaking cannot be distinguished from a valid value.
> In many cases however, a running system will have non-zero
> values, so using 0 instead of -1 to indicate an unknown
> quantity does not lose any functionality.

I think it's safe to say this is one of the cases where a zero is not valid, so you should take it to mean that there is no defined maximum.

Comment: Thank @TallChuck. But if the graph shown in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262328/how-is-the-java-memory-pool-divided) is correct, the *Eden/Survivor* max space should be defined by `-XX:MaxNewSize`, which, in fact, is found in the command line arguments (`-XX:MaxNewSize=3584m`) of the Java process. In other words, the max value of that Memory Pool is defined, but it is reported as "no defined"... odd

Comment: From my first comment above, how can be the initial size (3,946,840,064 shown as .10.4) larger than the MaxNewSize set in the `-XX:MaxNewSize=3584m` (3,758,096,384 bytes)?

Comment: `MaxNewSize` apples to the "Young Generation", which contains the Eden and Survivor spaces, but it doesn't directly set the maximum size of those spaces.